# How to load dropdown menu from Obj

Tags: javascript, html, json, object

I'm new to JS, and I'd like to ask for guidance on how to populate a dropdown menu once the page DOM loads using Javascript with the object I defined below. I looked at a few examples on here and in other places; however, I'm still unclear how to do this. In my code below, I can't quite understand what I should include in my opt.innerHTML? Is it ul li element with a variable that points to the object? Thanks for any help on this.

```
const score = document.querySelector('#score');

const output = document.querySelector('#output');

const answerSelect = document.querySelector('#selAnswers');

const categorgySelect = {
    
    Category: 'Sports',
    Category: 'Art',
    Category: 'Vehicles',
    Category: 'History',

};

const difficultySelect = {
    
    Difficulty: 'easy',
    Difficulty: 'medium',
    Difficulty: 'hard',
    

};

let categoryPick = document.querySelector('#category');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
         for(let index in categorySelect) {
            let opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = categorySelect;
            opt.innerHTML = ???

            categorySelect.appendChild(opt);
         }
});



<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>l</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/Trivia.css' >
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Trivia</h1>
    <div>Score: <span id="score">Correct 0 Wrong 0</span></div>
    <br>
    <div> 
        <label>Select Category:</label>
        <select id='category'></select>
        <br> 
        <label>Select Difficulty:</label>
        <select id='difficulty'></select>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="selAnswers"></div>
    <br>`enter code here`
    <button id="btn">Get First Question!</button>
    <script src ='js/Trivia.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Objects should have unique keys.

Try using array instead of objects.

```
const categorgySelect = [ 'Sports', 'Art', 'Vehicles', 'History' ];
const difficultySelect = [ 'easy', 'medium', 'hard' ];
```

Update Your For Loop like this,

```
let opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = categorySelect[index];
opt.innerHTML = categorySelect[index];
categoryPick.appendChild(opt)
```

You have to append to `select`.

Reference:

Objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Thank you for your response. I may have mentioned that I'm going to connect this to a simple API to generate questions that stores categories in the same way I listed in my object, unsure if that changes things?

Answer (score 0):

First off, typo in `const categorgySelect`: You probably meant `categorySelect`.
Also, "select" doesn't really fit for a name here, it would have been better to just call it `categories`. Same for `difficultySelect`.

You are assigning multiple values to one property:

```js
const categorgySelect = {
  Category: 'Sports',
  Category: 'Art',
  // ...
  Category: 'History'
};
```

This will override any previous defined value, meaning the object will only hold the last value for that property (here: `Category: 'History'`).

To hold an array of values, use an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):
**Note** the different brackets `[]`, because we are now creating an array using the array literal, and *not* an object using the object literal.

```js
const categorgySelect = [
  'Sports',
  'Art',
  // ...
  'History'
];
```

Same applies to `difficultySelect`.

Now in the `DOMContentLoaded` listener we want to populate the `<select>`s with `<option>`s. This can easily be done using a [for...of-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).
**Note:** A *for...of*-loop loops over the iterable properties of an object, while a [for...in-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops over the *enumerable* properties of an object (MDN goes into more detail about the [differences between for...of and for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Difference_between_for...of_and_for...in)). They might seem similar for arrays, but are quite different. Generally, one needs a for...of-loop, but always try to think about what you want to loop over.

We can either use `Element.innerHTML` (best with a pre-built String), or `Element.append()` to add the options to the select-elements.

Here are both selects populated using the two approaches described above:

```js
const categories = [ // Fixed name
  'Sports',
  'Art',
  'Vehicles',
  'History'
];

const difficulties = [ // Better name
  'easy',
  'medium',
  'hard'
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Moved inside listener to free up namespace
  let categorySelect = document.querySelector('#category');
  let difficultySelect = document.querySelector('#difficulty');

  let html = '';
  for (let item of categories) {
    // Appending Strings created using Template literals
    html += `<option>${item}</option>`;
  }
  categorySelect.innerHTML = html;
  
  for (let item of difficulties) {
    let opt = document.createElement('option');
    
    // <option> will use its .textContent as value if not explicitly defined
    opt.textContent = item;
    
    difficultySelect.append(opt);
  }
});
```

```css
label {display: block}
```

```html
<!-- Placed <select>-tags inside <label>-tags due to accessibility reasons -->

<label>Select Category:
  <select id='category'></select>
</label>
<label>Select Difficulty:
  <select id='difficulty'></select>
</label>
```